# Need collect array in loop and display when the user says no. C#

Tags: c#

I'm sorry if it sounds easy, I'm just a beginner. What did I do wrong?
I need to collect the array in every answer yes. I planned to have only 4 spaces to add cars and if the user has only 1/2/3 it will say no and also display only those. And add them individually to the List. Help me, please.

```
bool isRunning = true;

while (isRunning == true)
{
    List<String[]> cars = new List<string[]>();
    Console.Write("Here you write the brand of the car:");
    String bilMärke = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Here you write the Cars model: ");
    String modellBeteckning = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Here you write the color:");
    String farg = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    Console.Write("Here you write the years model: ");
    String årsModell = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Here you write the cars milage: ");
    String antalKM = Console.ReadLine();
    String[] car = new string[4];
    car[0] = " One " + bilMärke + ", *Model: " + modellBeteckning + ", *" + farg + ", *Year:" + årsModell + ", *" + antalKM + "Km ";
    car[1] = " One " + bilMärke + ", *Model: " + modellBeteckning + ", *" + farg + ", *Year:" + årsModell + ", *" + antalKM + "Km ";
    car[2] = " One " + bilMärke + ", *Model: " + modellBeteckning + ", *" + farg + ", *Year:" + årsModell + ", *" + antalKM + "Km ";
    car[3] = " One " + bilMärke + ", *Model: " + modellBeteckning + ", *" + farg + ", *Year:" + årsModell + ", *" + antalKM + "Km ";
    //all cars info //
    cars.Add(car);
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do you have other vehicle to sell? \n[1]Yes\n[2]No.");
        int answer= Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        if (answer == 1) {isRunning = true;}
        if (answer == 2) {
            isRunning = false;
        Console.Clear();
        foreach(String i in car)
        {
            Console.Write("So here we have your cars list: "+ i );
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the biggest problem here is that `List<String[]> cars = new List<string[]>();` needs to be outside `while`.

---

Here are some ideas that further improve the code:

```
bool isRunning = true;

List<String> cars = new List<string>();

while (isRunning == true)
{
    ...
    var car = " One " + bilMärke + ", *Model: " + modellBeteckning + ", *" + farg + ", *Year:" + årsModell + ", *" + antalKM + "Km ";
    //all cars info //
    cars.Add(car);

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do you have other vehicle to sell? \n[1]Yes\n[2]No.");
        //TODO2 maybe use int.TryParse (no try+catch is needed)
        var answer = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());


        if (answer == 1) 
        {
          isRunning = true;
        }
        if (answer == 2) 
        {
          isRunning = false;
        }    
        // TODO what if the answer is not 1 or 2?    
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       //TODO What to do? Maybe ask the question in a look until it's 1 or 2?
       
    }
}

Console.Clear();
foreach(var car in cars)
{
   Console.Write("So here we have your cars list: " + car );
}
Console.ReadKey();
```